# how to specify number of worksheets to create while doing late binding in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, late-binding

I need to specify number of worksheets to be created using late binding. Here is my code & exception says invalid index:

```
oSheets = oWB.GetType()
    .InvokeMember("Worksheets", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, oWB, new object[] { 7 });
```

Below code works and creating 3 worksheets,

```
oSheets = oWB.GetType()
    .InvokeMember("Worksheets", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, oWB, null );
```

Let me know what I need to do to create worksheets with a specified number.

Comment: Isn't it easier to use `dynamic`? e.g. `dynamic oWB = GetWB(); dynamic oSheets = oWB.Worksheets();`

Comment: I'm using `VS2005` with `.net 3.0`

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting an exception is that you are invoking a property and trying to pass a parameter to it. Excel by default creates 3 worksheets which is why the second line works. If you want to add more worksheets, you need to call the [`Workbook.Worksheets.Add()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.sheets.add.aspx) method and specify the count property. You can continue to use reflection as you asked but it's much easier to write (and read back) if you use the `dynamic` type:

```
dynamic oWB = GetWorkbook();
dynamic oSheets = oWB.Worksheets();

//We now have 3 worksheets, and now we will add 4 more
oSheets.Add(null, null, 4, xlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
```

And the enumeration if needed:

```
public enum xlSheetType
{
    xlWorksheet = -4167
}
```

Comment: I'm using `VS2005` with `.net 3.0`

Comment: You can still use reflection then, but you will need to get the sheets with the second line and then invoke the `Add` method on `oSheets`.